# Tracking number of selected items in each section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I could able to count the number of item selection for each section.

However, I wonder how I could able to keep tracking of all sections in one.

The following `rowcount` only returns me the number of items in the current section, but I need to keep track of number of items in other sections as well.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger rowcount =  [[self.comboTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] count];
}
```

By the way, user can able to choose as many items as he wants.

```
self.comboTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Comment: Why are you taking count instead of iterating the index paths get the selected section & row?

Comment: Could you please illustrate your approach?

Comment: do you want to get the sections and rows of the table view right?

Comment: `indexPathsForSelectedRows` will return all the selected rows independent of section.

Comment: when I looking into apple docs - `The value of this property is an array of index-path objects each identifying a row through its section and row index. The value of this property is nil if there are no selected rows.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the all the selected rows from all the sections. `indexPathsForSelectedRows` will return the `NSArray<NSIndexPath*>` of the table view. Not for a single section

```
- (void)selectedItem: (UITableView *)tableView {
    NSArray <NSIndexPath*> *selectedIndexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexpath in selectedIndexPaths) {
        NSLog(@"Section index : %ld", indexpath.section);
        NSLog(@"Row index : %ld", indexpath.row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my custom logic to keep watch your current selected row. This logic won't affect any of your current logic.

Declare variable in .h file and init into **viewDidLoad** method.

```
dicSelectedRow = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

Make below changes into your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** and **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** mehtod.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        // put your allocation code at here      

        // To check if current section's row is selected or not...
        NSString *strCurrentSection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)indexPath.section];
        NSString *strCurrentIndexPathRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)indexPath.row];
        NSMutableArray *aryCurrentSelectedRow = [NSMutableArray new];
        [aryCurrentSelectedRow addObjectsFromArray:dicSelectedRow[strCurrentSection]];
        if(aryCurrentSelectedRow.count > 0)
        {
            if([aryCurrentSelectedRow containsObject:strCurrentIndexPathRow])
            {
                // Your row is selected
            }
            else
            {
                // Your row is not selected
            }
        }

        aryCurrentSelectedRow = nil;


}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Here we need to check if row is there into dic or not.
    NSString *strCurrentSection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)indexPath.section];
    NSString *strCurrentIndexPathRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)indexPath.row];
    if(![dicSelectedRow valueForKey:strCurrentSection])
    {
        // We need to add key first....
        [dicSelectedRow setObject:[NSMutableArray new] forKey:strCurrentSection];
    }


    // Now we need to check if Current Selected Row is there or not.
    NSMutableArray *aryCurrentSelectedRow = [NSMutableArray new];
    [aryCurrentSelectedRow addObjectsFromArray:dicSelectedRow[strCurrentSection]];

    if([aryCurrentSelectedRow containsObject:strCurrentIndexPathRow])
        [aryCurrentSelectedRow removeObject:strCurrentIndexPathRow];
    else
        [aryCurrentSelectedRow addObject:strCurrentIndexPathRow];


    if(aryCurrentSelectedRow.count > 0)
    {
        // If current selection is having value then we replace this to main dic.
        [dicSelectedRow setObject:aryCurrentSelectedRow forKey:strCurrentSection];
    }
    else
    {
        // Remove key from Dic.
        [dicSelectedRow removeObjectForKey:strCurrentSection];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",dicSelectedRow.description);

    [_tblData reloadData];
}
```

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedRows: Int? = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()?.count
    var selectedCell: UITableViewCell?
    var selectedCellText: String
    var selections = [Any]()
    for index: IndexPath in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() {
        selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index)
        selectedCellText = selectedCell?.textLabel?.text
        selections.append(selectedCellText)
    }
    print("Total selections: \(Int(selectedRows))")
    print("selections: \(selections)")
}
```